# method or data member not found error in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I getting error

> method or data member not for

in below code at line

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    UserForm1.CommandButton2.Visible = True
    UserForm1.CommandButton1.Visible = False
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Visible = False
    UserForm1.TextBox2.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Label1.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Label2.Visible = False
    UserForm1.TextBox4.Visible = True
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Visible = True
    UserForm1.ComboBox2.Visible = True
    UserForm1.ComboBox3.Visible = True
    UserForm1.TextBox23.Visible = True
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line? Do all those controls exist on the form ?

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem for my self

Comment: @Robin thanks for mentioning it....i re checked and solved the problem